# Where can I find the first edition of the Stone Chumash?

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

Deuteronomy 27:2-3 says:

> וְהָיָ֗ה בַּיּוֹם֮ אֲשֶׁ֣ר תַּעַבְר֣וּ אֶת־הַיַּרְדֵּן֒ אֶל־הָאָ֕רֶץ
> אֲשֶׁר־יְהוָ֥ה אֱלֹהֶ֖יךָ נֹתֵ֣ן לָ֑ךְ וַהֲקֵמֹתָ֤ לְךָ֙ אֲבָנִ֣ים
> גְּדֹל֔וֹת וְשַׂדְתָּ֥ אֹתָ֖ם בַּשִּֽׂיד׃ וְכָתַבְתָּ֣ עֲלֵיהֶ֗ן
> אֶֽת־כָּל־דִּבְרֵ֛י הַתּוֹרָ֥ה הַזֹּ֖את בְּעָבְרֶ֑ךָ לְמַ֡עַן אֲשֶׁר֩
> תָּבֹ֨א אֶל־הָאָ֜רֶץ אֲ‍ֽשֶׁר־יְהוָ֥ה אֱלֹהֶ֣יךָ ׀ נֹתֵ֣ן לְךָ֗ אֶ֣רֶץ
> זָבַ֤ת חָלָב֙ וּדְבַ֔שׁ כַּאֲשֶׁ֥ר דִּבֶּ֛ר יְהוָ֥ה
> אֱלֹהֵֽי־אֲבֹתֶ֖יךָ לָֽךְ׃
>
> And it shall be on the day when ye shall pass over the Jordan unto the
> land which the LORD thy God giveth thee, that thou shalt set thee up
> great stones, and plaster them with plaster. And thou shalt write upon
> them all the words of this law, when thou art passed over; that thou
> mayest go in unto the land which the LORD thy God giveth thee, a land
> flowing with milk and honey, as the LORD, the God of thy fathers, hath
> promised thee.

In the beginning of the book of Joshua, we see that the Israelites fulfilled the commandment to write the first Stone Chumash, as commanded in the above verses.

The Stone Chumash has become a popular Chumash in many, mainly Orthodox, synagogues, esp. in U.S.A. I assume that the current version is a much later edition than the original one made at Gilgal several millennia ago. Has anyone located the original Stone Chumash? What translation did they use in place ofw and English? What did they substitute for Rash"i's commentary and Targum Onkelos, since they didn't live at that time?

(Kudos to a local rav who alluded to the Stone Chumash concept when I was in a Sefer Yehoshua shiur he conducted a few years ago.)

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Answer (score 3):

Yehoshua 8:30-32:

> אָז יִבְנֶה יְהוֹשֻׁעַ מִזְבֵּחַ, לַיהוָה אֱלֹהֵי יִשְׂרָאֵל,
>   בְּהַר, עֵיבָל... וַיִּכְתָּב-שָׁם,
>   עַל-הָאֲבָנִים--אֵת, מִשְׁנֵה תּוֹרַת מֹשֶׁה, אֲשֶׁר כָּתַב, לִפְנֵי
>   בְּנֵי יִשְׂרָאֵל.
>
> Then Joshua built an altar unto the LORD, the God of Israel, on
>   **mount Evil**... and he wrote there upon the stones a copy of the
>   law of Moses, which he wrote before the children of Israel.

According to the esteemed [Rav Google](http://www.preoccupiedterritory.com/rabbinate-considers-granting-ordination-to-google/) shlit"a, [Mount Evil](https://www.google.com/search?q=mount%20evil&oq=mount&aqs=chrome.0.69i59j69i57j0l4.1312j0j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8) is somewhere in Tennessee. You may be able to find the Chumash on street view.